# Unable to route from Modal window in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, routes, bootstrap-modal

I have a button in UI. On click on that, i am opening a bootstrap modal window. There is an another button in my modal window. I want to navigate to different route on click on that button in modal window.

```
$('#cartModal').modal('hide');
$location.path('/AngularJS/phonecat/#phones/address');
```

But it only close the modal popup, doesn't route to the given path.

Earlier route before opening the modal window: /AngularJS/phonecat/#phones
Expected route after closing the modal window: /AngularJS/phonecat/#phones/address

I am unable to find that why it's not working. Kindly help.

I tried to get some code part from the main application. Hope it will help.
http://jsbin.com/vizequ/2/edit?html,js

Comment: By adding the code snippet it will increase your change to get the fruitful suggestions and answers

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the code snippet to change routes on the hide event of the model.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $location.path('/AngularJS/phonecat/#phones/address');
});
```

If this does not help, can you post a more verbose code or a jsFiddle?

Comment: You are attaching the event after hiding your modal. Events should be attached at load time.

Comment: I know. I tried the same also. While initializing the controller, i listen this event and set the route path. It's not listening the event while closing the modal window. On click on that modal button, i am just hiding the modal window. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I was assigning the wrong path to router. On click of modal window's button, i have written the code below.

```
$location.path('/phones/address');
$('#cartModal').modal('hide');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

It solved my problem. Hope it will help others.